# Is this phase right?

Tags: waves, conventions

Hello at physics lectures we wrote a phase of a sine wave like this:

$$\phi = kx - \omega t$$

Is this right? As I recall the phase of a wave should be written like this:

$$\phi = \omega t - kx$$

And if a wave changes direction $(k \rightarrow -k)$ like this:

$$\phi = \omega t + kx$$

Can someone explain to me if first usage is even possible and when if so.

Comment: The first two phases are the same, the sine only differs by an overall sign i.e. by normalization. The last formula only differs by its being a left-moving wave rather than a right-moving wave, i.e. by the sign of $k$.

Comment: Soo it holds that $\sin(x) = - \sin(-x)$ and therefore $\sin(\omega t - kx) = - \sin(kx - \omega t)$?

Comment: Could you post your anwser below so i can give you points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It holds that $\sin(x) = - \sin(-x)$ and therefore $\sin(\omega t - kx) = - \sin(kx - \omega t)$.